# pings ignored across VPN with Centos 7

Tags: centos, vpn, ping, tcpdump

I'm trying to setup a CentOS 7 DNS server in a VPN.  I can't get devices from the VPN subnet (different subnet) to ping servers.  I can get pings to work between servers (same subnet)

When I run `tcpdump -nvi eth1 icmp` I can see the following:

When `10.4.1.21` pings `10.4.1.2`:

```
10:26:58.348366 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20006, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.21 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 17034, seq 1, length 64
10:26:58.348438 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39037, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.2 > 10.4.1.21: ICMP echo reply, id 17034, seq 1, length 64
10:26:59.348266 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20913, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.21 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 17034, seq 2, length 64
10:26:59.348325 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39998, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.2 > 10.4.1.21: ICMP echo reply, id 17034, seq 2, length 64
10:27:00.348248 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21633, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.21 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 17034, seq 3, length 64
10:27:00.348306 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40058, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.4.1.2 > 10.4.1.21: ICMP echo reply, id 17034, seq 3, length 64
```

However, when `10.10.79.34` pings `10.4.1.2`, all I see are requests but no replies

```
10:32:12.225281 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3592, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 78, length 40
10:32:17.250644 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3593, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 79, length 40
10:32:22.129885 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3594, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 80, length 40
10:32:27.389271 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3595, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 81, length 40
10:32:32.149386 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3596, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 82, length 40
10:32:37.269775 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3597, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 83, length 40
10:32:42.157175 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 3598, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    10.10.79.34 > 10.4.1.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 84, length 40
```

It seems to me that the CentOS server is swallowing the requests. I can't find anything in the logs to help so far.  I've got the firewall turned off.

The laptop at `10.10.79.34` is able to ping the gateway at `10.4.1.1`.

Comment: What is the output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`?

Comment: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

Comment: I just enabled it -- it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. But you did `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on the gateway? And your client with address `10.4.1.21` has a route back to `10.10.79.34`?

Comment: I have. Didn't work. (client is 10.10.79.34 (windows) and server is 10.4.1.21 (linux))